# Core plot set x-axis position of first majortick

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have the following chart done with CorePlot on the iPhone:
[image]

and I am trying to get the first major tick of the x-axis no to appear at the begging of the axis. Is there a way to tell the axisSet where the first major tick should be?
I am trying to accomplish to have fixed times, like every 15minuter or every hour and I suppose if I get the first date value correct the next will follow.

Comment: Which labeling policy are you using?

Comment: CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval and x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat([lastDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate]/6); to get the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `labelingOrigin`. The `majorIntervalLength` defines the space between successive major tick marks, starting at the labeling origin. The origin value doesn't have to be in the visible plot range so you don't have to adjust it when scrolling the plot.